# Выполнить действие из формулы JS

Tags: javascript

Имеется такое выражение в виде строки `12*3000`. Что мне сделать так что бы это посчиталось как с цифрами?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`eval(12*3000);` и она вернет 36000